# Bootstrap CSS keeps over rescaling my self hosted videos

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, html5-video

I'm learning bootstrap 3 and I'm facing the problem - my self hosted videos are always bigger than they have to be on large screens.
Here's my bootstrap code I'm using from tutorials (basic template). I'm trying to add a 464x288 video to a single size-12 column row:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
                    <video class="embed-responsive-item" width="464" height='288' controls> 
                        <source src="Bad_Taste.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        <source src="Bad_Taste.webm" type="video/webm"> 
                        <source src="Bad_Taste.ogv" type="video/ogg">
                        I'm sorry; your browser doesn't support HTML5 video.
                    </video>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The rendered result makes the height and width of the vid several times bigger:
[my rendered result - over resized vid][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvzMz.jpg .
How can I keep the original resolution? I tried to use combinations of "col-xs(md|lg)-6", "col-xs(md|lg)-5" and so on and it helped to prevent over resizing, but since I've got videos with different resolutions, I'm looking for one html/css code wich could fit all videos without making them bigger on large screens.

Comment: try to remove embed-responsive. I guess responsive tag gives it a width of 100%

Comment: Removing "embed-responsive" brings back the correct video resolution, but it stops autoshrinking the video for smaller displays.

Comment: Just checked this issue with Foundation 5 - the same problem with over resing, videos are too huge. But in a few minutes I found a solution - adding 'style="max-height: px;max-width: px;"' to 'flex-video' wrapper fixes the problem. Before I did the same with Bootstrap - still problems with correct resolutions, now videos are too small. Still looking how to fix it in Bootstrap.

Comment: I suggest posting it as an answer and accepting or or marking this as completed.

Answer (score 0):

With Bootstrap 3 it should be possible to solve it like this (or of course add your own CSS class):

```
.embed-responsive-item {
    max-width: 464px;
    max-height: 288px;
}
```